# How to assign an icon to a program in Openbox?

Tags: openbox, icons

I am running on Arch Linux using Openbox as the window manager. I want to assign icons to some programs that are using the generic icon.

This is helpful because when I do an Alt-Tab, I will know the program based on the icon it shows. Currently, I have some programs, like Xterm and Xpdf, using the default icon and doing an Alt-Tab when both are open can be confusing.

I have Firefox, Geany and Leafpad installed and I noticed that they have icons during an Alt-Tab.

So how do I set this up for the other programs that don't?

Answer (score 9):

If you are talking about icons in your panel (like [tint2](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/), for example), then you can use [xseticon](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/) (there is a [PKGBUILD in AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=39064)).

You can set an icon for an application like so:

```
xseticon -id "$WINDOWID" path/to/icon.png
```

Comment: I am not using Tint2 or any panel for that matter. I just want to change the icon of the program when Alt-Tab is pressed.

Comment: Did you try xseticon? Did it not work?

Comment: I just tried it now. And it works! Thanks for this.

Comment: And I also noticed that when I close the window that I have assigned an icon to, and reopen it, it goes back to the default icon (and not the one I assigned). :(

Comment: Did you put it in your autostart script? That would set it for your session.

Comment: Do you have an example? What I did was just to `xseticon path/to/icon.png` and when the cursor turned to a crosshair I clicked the running app I wanted to set the icon to. I don't know how to get the value `-id <window_id>`.

Comment: `if [ "$TERM" = "rxvt-unicode-256color" ]; then
  xseticon -id "$WINDOWID" /usr/share/pixmaps/urxvtc.png
fi`

Answer (score 0):

As jasonwryan says, you can use `xseticon` to set the icon of windows. If you want to do this automatically, you can use [Devil's Pie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie).

I created a small script that sets a window's icon based on the current GNOME icon theme (it can easily be adapted to work with KDE). [Here](https://gist.github.com/SparklePigBang/54bc739131cc98f8d226) it is.

The corresponding Devil's Pie configuration looks like:

```
(spawn_sync "/path/to/set-xdg-icon.sh" (str (window_xid)))
```

This requires `xseticon`, `pyxdg` and `xprop`.